# bootstrap popover showing in the wrong element

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use the bootstrap popover on a click. 
I first initalize at the start of my js onReady.
Then I add a show option but it appends it to the wrong dom element. 
It should be placing it in the wrapper element.

```
var wrapper = $(".modal .modal-wrapper");
wrapper.popover({trigger:'manual', title:"WORKING TOOLTIP", selector:wrapper});
```

Then this is called on a click of a button.

```
var showTooltip = function( ){
    wrapper.popover('show');
}
```

The issue is the popover is not showing inside the wrapper div its showing in the body element instead. how can I get it to show inside the wrapper element.

Answer (score 2):

The `selector` attribute only serves for delegated events if triggered by the plugin.

First of all, this selector **[will not be used](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/ebc69356637143c938c07904d10928c11e742196/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js#L47)** if you set `trigger: 'manual'`.

Then, if (for example) you have `trigger: 'hover'` and have that markup :

```html
<div class="megadiv">
    <button class="btn">Hover me</button>
</div>
```

The following javascript will bind **one** popup to appear on any hovering `.btn`

```js
$('.megadiv').popover({
    selector: '.btn',
    content: 'content',
    title: 'title'    
});
```

[Live demo (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/PpQXk/)

And this only applies to child elements of `.megadiv`. See the [`jQuery.on` doc](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) for that.

> The handler is not called when the event occurs directly on the bound element, but only for descendants (inner elements) that match the selector.

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this.  I think the selector property takes a string not an object

```
wrapper.popover({trigger:'manual', title:"WORKING TOOLTIP", selector: ".modal .modal-wrapper" });
```

from http://www.w3resource.com/twitter-bootstrap/popover-tutorial.php

> selector
>
> Type of the value of the selector is string, default value is false.    Tooltip objects are delegated to the given target by using this.

Comment: Thanks wiry but its still showing up appended to the body and not the wrapper element.

Comment: are you able to make a fiddle and replicate this?  or have a link to your site?

Comment: I decided for now to just build my own its faster. I will revisit this when I have more time. Thanks for the help.