# Twitter's Bootstrap 2.x Popover Selector & Closing Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

having a bit of trouble with bootstrap's popover component.

One of my forms can have multiple dynamically added elements so I need to dynamically add a popover to all of these using the popover's selector option. This works fine.

I want to close the other popups when a new one is clicked on though, so I'm also using `$(body).on("click", "selector")` and calling `$('selector').not(this).popover('hide');` this for some reason this seems to cause issues, the first popup clicked on will show then none others will and it gets all buggy.

If I change the popover to not use a selector however this works. Only thing I can think of is is there something in the way jQuery is ordering the events being fired?

http://jsfiddle.net/nzM6F/10/

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, using the `selector:` in the popover is buggy.

Try this:

```
$("[rel=popover]").popover({
    content: bindToMe,
    placement: 'right',
    html: true
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/skelly/nzM6F/11/

You'll also get better performance than the `body` selector.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I need to use the selector however as elements are being added to the form dynamically

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the popover() to your .popover class:

```
$("body").append('<div id="popover">I am popover content</div>');
$('#popover').hide();

var bindToMe = $("#popover").html();

$(".pover").popover({
    content: bindToMe,
    placement: 'right',
    html: true,
    trigger: 'manual'
});

$(".pover").click(function(e) {
    $(".pover").not($(this)).popover('hide');
    $(this).popover('show');
  });
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/bassjobsen/nzM6F/15/

Comment: thanks for the reply. However I require popover to use selector as elements will be continually added to the form that I want to have the popover applied to. Also I want the popover to point to the div not make a copy so it keeps all of the events and data and holds the last used state.

Comment: In your case a popover create a new div with `class = "popover fade right in"`. For this reason `$(".pover").not($(this)).popover('hide');` doesn't hide your popover. I found you could remove the "in" class instead, see: http://jsfiddle.net/bassjobsen/nzM6F/16/. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/a/11850832/1596547